# Using PHP in_array to match a string

Tags: php, arrays

Starting off I have two PHP arrays.

The first array has a length of dates in `Y-m` order that has each of the 12 months in it with the years. This array looks like this...

```
Array
( 
    [0] => Array ( [ORDER] => Array ( [DATE] => 2008-10 [QTY] => 0 ) ) 
    [1] => Array ( [ORDER] => Array ( [DATE] => 2008-11 [QTY] => 0 ) ) 
)
```

The second array has values that have been returned from a query and put into the array and are also in `Y-m` order for may or may not have each month in it. The second one is like this.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array ( [ORDER] => Array ( [DATE] => 2008-11 [QTY] => 285 ) )
    [1] => Array ( [ORDER] => Array ( [DATE] => 2008-12 [QTY] => 900 ) )
)
```

My end goal is to produce an array of the Y-m dates to use for a google line chart that will show a 0 if in that month no orders where placed. So that array should look like this..

```
Array
( 
    [0] => Array ( [ORDER] => Array ( [DATE] => 2008-10 [QTY] => 0 ) ) 
    [1] => Array ( [ORDER] => Array ( [DATE] => 2008-11 [QTY] => 285 ) ) 
    [2] => Array ( [ORDER] => Array ( [DATE] => 2008-12 [QTY] => 900 ) )

)
```

So the array item...

`[1] => Array ( [ORDER] => Array ( [DATE] => 2008-11 [QTY] => 0 ) )`

was removed as there was an entry in the second array that had a value with the same date.

Now I'm not sure if I'm going about this the right way but here's what I have so far.

```
foreach($FIRST_ARRAY as $key => $each)
{
    foreach($each as $line)
    {
        $findMe = $line['DATE'];

            if(in_array($findMe, $SECOND_ARRAY, true))
                {   
                    echo 'FOUND:'.$findMe;

                }else{          
                    echo $line['DATE'].'&nbsp;';
                    echo $line['QTY'].'&nbsp;';
                    echo '('.$findMe.')<br>';
                }
    }
}
```

All this is doing is printing out the First Array. It's not 'Matching' up the dates.
Here's what its printing out...

2008-10 0 (2008-10)
2008-11 0 (2008-11)
2008-12 0 (2008-12)

Here's what I want it to print out...

2008-10 0 (2008-10)
2008-11 285 (2008-11)
2008-12 900 (2008-12)

**The Question would be: Am I going about this all wrong or is there a better way of doing this.**

I hope this all makes sense.

Comment: Are these values coming from a database? You can also make a SUM in a query, no need to do this in php.

Comment: Will your two arrays be pre-sorted by `yyyy-mm` in ascending order?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try

```
$array = array(0 => array('DATE' => '2008-10','QTY' => 0),1 => array('DATE' => '2008-11','QTY' => 0));
$array2 = array(0 => array('DATE' => '2008-11','QTY' => 285),1 => array('DATE' => '2008-12','QTY' => 900));

$final = array();

groupAdd($final, $array, "DATE");
groupAdd($final, $array2, "DATE");

foreach ( $final as $line ) {
    echo $line['DATE'] . '&nbsp;';
    echo $line['QTY'] . '&nbsp;';
    echo '(' . $line['DATE'] . ')<br>';
}
```

Output

```
2008-10 0 (2008-10)
2008-11 285 (2008-11)
2008-12 900 (2008-12)
```

Function Used

```
function groupAdd(&$final, $array, $groupKey) {
    foreach ( $array as $item ) {
        isset($final[$item[$groupKey]]) ? $final[$item[$groupKey]]['QTY'] += $item['QTY'] : $final[$item[$groupKey]] = $item;
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow. That was even simpler that I thought it would be. Thanks!

Comment: Now, what about if I needed more items in the array. How would I set that up?

Comment: what you you mean by more items ???? It should work if you are only dealing with DATE and QTY

Comment: It works perfect. But I'd like to add to it by adding more array values to it. Like if the arrays where like: [0] => Array ( [ORDER] => Array ( [DATE] => 2008-11 [QTY] => 285 [DISPLAYQTY] => 285 [ORDERID] => 5551231 ) )

Comment: @Monty  You would need some modification because of order ID

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17944/discussion-between-monty-and-baba)

Comment: The only thing is that it's adding up the Order_ID fields what do I need to do to get the Order_IDs to append each other instead of adding like the QTY fields do?

Comment: You can always modify the function i gave you to do that

Answer (score 0):

```
$ans = Array();
$tmp_second_array = $SECOND_ARRAY;
foreach($FIRST_ARRAY as $key => $each){
 $arr_to_add = $each;
 if(!empty($tmp_second_array)){
  foreach($tmp_second_array as $seckey => $seceach){
   if($each['ORDER']['DATE'] === $seceach['ORDER']['DATE']){   
     $arr_to_add = $seceach;
     unset($tmp_second_array[$seckey])
     break;
   }
  }
  $ans[] = $arr_to_add;
 }           
}
if(!empty($tmp_second_array)){
 $ans = array_merge($ans, $tmp_second_array);
}
```